# How long Hbase need to take for recovering one crashed RegionServer

Tags: hbase

It seems Hbase RegionServer is a single node, not like Cassandra there are replicate nodes. I know when one RegionServer down, the HMaster will assign the regions which on the crashed RS to other RS.

but how long the new RegionServer would be ready for serving the crashed regions, If it took too long, the client can not wait too long and client will throw exception even lost data, right please?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you are looking for is **HBase Mean Time To Recovery**.
There are some articles talking about it. To answer your question based on this [article](http://hortonworks.com/blog/introduction-to-hbase-mean-time-to-recover-mttr/):

**How long does Hbase take to recover from a failure**

it depends on your settings, your hbase version, your hardware...
There are 3 steps for this process:

1. Identify that a region server is down. This is done by a process called heartbeat executed by Zookeeper. If the region server does not answer to the heartbeat before the Timeout, the master will consider the regionServer dead.
2. Recovering the writes in progress: Before writing to a region server, the writes are preserved in a log. Because the data is replicated, let's say three times, if a node crash, you still have two logs with the right values. so when the master knows a region server is dead, it will try to recover his last state reading the log.
3. Reassigning the region: it depends on your HBase version

**Is data lost in the meantime?**

Yes, the client is blocked until the recovery is done. That's why there are ways to minimize this down time by playing with the settings of hbase and zookeeper. see [this blog post](http://www.openkb.info/2014/05/how-to-shorten-hbase-mttr.html) for the manipulation.

**EDIT**

As said by FengWang, I might imply that HBase takes a long time to recover from a failure. Compare to Cassandra, it does take more resources to recover a node. This can be explained by the **CAP theorem**: Hbase with its master/regionServer architecture is **consistent** and **partition tolerant** but **not available**. However, Cassandra with its peer to peer like architecture is **available** and **partition tolerant** but **not consistent**.

This is only generality, because in fact, you can tune HBase to be available with the right configuration and scheme (like FengWang have), but you will loose other things. Having 100 nodes where you could have 10 nodes with bigger storing capacities is a big price difference. Also, having to query more nodes for a scan is not cost efficient but with fine tuning you can overcome this problem (with a good data scheme you can avoid to scan across too many nodes). In Cassandra case, you can set a consistency level on queries. The higher the level, the slower the query.

In distributed system, you can only trade one thing for another. There is no generic solution for a problem.

Answer (score 3):

I did some tests on 100 nodes Hbase cluster. When one RegionServer down Hbase usually take 3-5 seconds to reload the missed regions and Hlog from HDFS. i.e The client only was blocked less than 5 seconds. Not like the above post said that it will take 1 minute. If it really need to take 1 minute I bet no one wants to use Hbase.

While for Cassandra, if one node is down, it usually take less than 1 second to reload the missed data.

Comment: Did not talk about any specific down time but your experiment is interesting.  It would be good to know your settings

Comment: And also,  your statement about the client not accepting a downtime of minutes is wrong, it depends on how You use your data

Comment: Thanks for your comments, we use Hbase as our on-line realtime database.    For providing internal email retrieve by md5. We keep the regions number lower and region size smaller, we did meet the RS downtime, but the recovery time usually take about 2 seconds. If it took 1 minute to recover and response to users, we would not choose Hbase couple years ago.

Comment: will edit my answer with your remark and a small explaination of the CAP theorem